# A normal projective surface with quotient singularities with $b_2(S)=1$ satisfies $b_1(S)=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

According to this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602562.pdf, in p.2 (below Theorem 1), it is written that if $S$ is a normal projective surface (so there are only finitely many isolated singularities) with quotient singularities (its definition is given in p.1) and $b_2(S)=1$, then $b_1(S)=0$ by looking at the Albanese map, but I can't see why.

The Albanese map is defined as follows: Fix a basepoint $x_0\in S$, let $H^0(S,\Omega^1)$ be the space of global holomorphic 1-forms and $H^0(S,\Omega^1)^*$ its dual. There is a natural map $H_1(S,\Bbb Z)\to H^0(S,\Omega^1)^*$ defined by $[\gamma] \mapsto (\alpha \to \int_\gamma \alpha)$. The albanese map is defined by $\text{alb}:S\to \text{Alb}(S):=H^0(S,\Omega^1)^*/H_1(S,\Bbb Z)$, $~~\text{alb}(x)=(\alpha\mapsto \int_{x_0}^x \alpha)$. How can we use this map to show that $b_1(S)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an argument in the smooth case, I guess it is not so hard to generalise to your situation, although I didn't check all of the details (in particular all of the relevant invariants are well-defined). Assume for  contradiction that $b_1(S)>0$ so $h^{1,0}(S) = q(S) \geq 1$.

The geometric genus is defined as the Hodge number $p_g=h^{2,0}(S)$. Since $b_2(S)=1$, clearly $p_g = h^{2,0}(S)=0$. Since $b_2(S)=2h^{2,0}(S) + h^{1,1}(S)$.

Then, by Lemma 10.18 of Beauville's "Complex Algebraic Surfaces" the image of the Albenese map is a curve. Let $F \in H^{2}(S,\mathbb{Z})$ be the class of a fibre. Then $F^2 = 0$ and $[\omega].F > 0$, where $[\omega]$ is the Kahler form.  This implies that $[\omega]$ and $F$ are linearly independent in $H^{2}(S,\mathbb{R})$ hence $b_{2}(S) \geq 2$, a contradiction.

For sure if you can prove that the image of the Albenese map is a curve then the above argument shows $b_{2}\geq 2$ also with singularities.